# How to get bash built in commands using Perl

Tags: linux, perl

I was wondering if there is a way to get Linux commands with a perl script. I am talking about commands such as `cd ls ll clear cp`

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What does ls and cp make linux commands? On my system they are simple programs located in /bin? lorenzo@enzo:/bin$ file ls
ls: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, stripped

Comment: I am assuming you are talking about getting linux type commands within another OS, as perl scripts? Such as windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can execute system commands in a variety of ways, some better than others.

- Using `system();`, which prints the output of the command, but does not return the output to the Perl script.
- Using backticks (``), which don't print anything, but return the output to the Perl script. An alternative to using actual backticks is to use the `qx();` function, which is easier to read and accomplishes the same thing.
- Using `exec();`, which does the same thing as `system();`, but does not return to the Perl script at all, unless the command doesn't exist or fails.
- Using `open();`, which allows you to either pipe input from your script to the command, or read the output of the command into your script.

It's important to mention that the system commands that you listed, like `cp` and `ls` are much better done using built-in functions in Perl itself. Any system call is a slow process, so use native functions when the desired result is something simple, like copying a file.

Some examples:

```
# Prints the output. Don't do this.
system("ls");

# Saves the output to a variable. Don't do this.
$lsResults = `ls`;

# Something like this is more useful.
system("imgcvt", "-f", "sgi", "-t", "tiff", "Image.sgi", "NewImage.tiff");
```

[This page](http://www.perlhowto.com/executing_external_commands) explains in a bit more detail the different ways that you can make system calls.

Comment: `system 'imgcvt', '-f', 'sgi', '-t', 'tiff', 'SomeImage.sgi', 'SomeNewImage.tiff'; # better`

Comment: I would discourage the use of backticks. The `qx();` syntax is clearer and much easier to read. I would also discourage the use of external commands. Too many people use `cp` or `copy` to copy files when `File::Copy` is readily available. Use Perl native commands and modules before you use external commands.

Comment: @David: Yes, good points. I updated the answer to include them.

Answer (score 2):

You can, as voithos says, using either `system()` or backticks. However, take into account that this is not recommended, **and** that, for instance, `cd` won't work (won't actually change the directory). Note that those commands are executed in a *new* shell, and won't affect the running perl script.

I would not rely on those commands and try to implement your script in Perl (if you're decided to use Perl, anyway). In fact, Perl was designed at first to be a powerful substitute for sh and other UNIX shells for sysadmins.

Comment: I assumed that he was asking how to execute system commands in general. If he really wants to run `ls` or `cd`, then no, he should not use system calls.

Comment: @voithos, the problem is that, asking for `cd` means he or she doesn't have very clear how these commands are engineered...

Comment: I agree. I've seen too many people use system commands like `cp` or `mail` when using built in Perl modules and functions would work much, much better.

Answer (score 0):

you can surround the command in back ticks
  `command`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is perl is trying to execute the bash builtin (i.e. `source`, ...) as if they were real files, but perl can't find them as they don't exist. The answer is to tell perl what to execute explicitly. In the case of bash builtins like `source`, do the following and it works just fine.

```
my $XYZZY=`bash -c "source SOME-FILE; DO_SOMETHING_ELSE; ..."`;
```

of for the case of `cd` do something like the following.

```
my $LOCATION=`bash -c "cd /etc/init.d; pwd"`;
```